# Passing variable through <a href> to $_SESSION without a form

Tags: php, jquery, session

I have a basic textarea in a form, and a link in another section of the page. What I'd like to do is if the user inputted any value in the textarea before clicking the link, to save this value in, say, $_SESSION['value'] so that I can re-enter it when they come back.

```
<body>

<form method="post" action="sent.php">
    <textarea id="text" name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
...
<div>
    <a id="test" href="away.php">Go here</a>
</div>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#test").click(function(){
      var value = $('#text').val();

//pass this value in somewhere before I'm redirected?

});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy.  You just need to update the `href` of the link.  The redirect won't happen till the click function has completed -

```
$("#test").click(function(event) {
  var value = $('#text').val();
  $("#test").attr("href", $("#test").attr("href") + "?text=" + $("#text").val());
});
```

Comment: So simple, exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

You can save it to session, every time you leave the textarea, and load it back if exists upon page load

```
$('#textarea').focusout(function(){
    //save to session
    $.post('url', {val:$('#textarea').val()});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code.

```
   <a href="#" name="test">Go Here</a>
```

The JQuery Code

```
   $(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'a[name=test]', function(){
            var textareaContent = $("#text").val();
            var data = {
                content:textareaContent
            };
            $.post('url', data, function(response){
                window.location.href="away.php";
            });
        });
      });
```